# Error parsing thymeleaf template

Tags: spring, template-engine, thymeleaf

this is bugging me for a while and there seems to be nothing helpful online; basically I can't find anything for the particular exception message, and I have no idea what to look for other than the exception message.

I've got a receipt page in my application, that used to work, but now it throws

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error processing template: dialect prefix "th" is set as non-lenient but attribute "th:src" has not been removed during process (/static/receipt:57)
```

where `th:src` is the first occurrence of a 'th' element. I don't do any custom processing - just an HTML page with a very little thymeleaf. The page gets parsed, as when I have errors in the syntax, it tells me that Thymeleaf engine failed to parse the page.
Also to mention, this page was generated by MS Word and then adapted for my needs. It is possible to rewrite it from scratch, but I'd like to find out what is not working and why it keeps giving me this message anyway.

MY problem seems to be identical to this forum entry http://forum.broadleafcommerce.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=1478 (the guy didn't get an answer).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out it was due to the datatables4j dialect added to the Thymeleaf template engine. The receipt page in question has a table that was not marked with the datatables4j notation. It led to the errors described in the question. As soon as I've removed the dialect, all the datatables4j tables were gone from everywhere, but so was the exception.

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more the issue you encountered with DataTables4j ? Thanks

Comment: The problem was with the version 0.8.2. The dialect was defined for the entire project, but one of the pages had a plain table without datatables4j. As soon as I tried to load the page, it would throw an exception.

Comment: Thanks. We'll investigate this issue (the fix will be part of the new project [Dandelion-Datatables](http://dandelion.github.com/datatables).

Comment: For information, this [bug](https://github.com/dandelion/issues/issues/149) will be fixed in Dandelion-Datatables 0.9.0