# Thymeleaf templated tables break when dandelion dataTablesDialect is present

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, dandelion

I have a basic table where some values are being provided by thymeleaf via `th:text=` tags.

That all works fine until we added the dandelion.datatables.thymeleaf.dialect.DataTablesDialect as a second dialect to our template engine.

with the dataTables dialect present, I get the following exception at the first instance of `th:text`

```
 org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error processing template: dialect prefix "th" is set as non-lenient but attribute "th:text" has not been removed during process
```

This appears to be nearly the same issue listed here: [Error parsing thymeleaf template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14950195/error-parsing-thymeleaf-template) but I am hopeful that there is a better solution than "don't use the dataTablesDialect"

Thanks

--------------- Update -----------------------------------------

My Java config:

```
@Bean
public ThymeleafViewResolver thymeleafViewResolver() {
    ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
    viewResolver.setViewNames(new String[]{"template*"});
    viewResolver.setOrder(1);

    return viewResolver;
}

@Bean
public ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
    ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();

    templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
    templateResolver.setCacheable(false);

    return templateResolver;
}

@Bean
public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
    SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();

    templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
    templateEngine.addDialect(dataTablesDialect());

    return templateEngine;
}

@Bean
public DataTablesDialect dataTablesDialect() {
    return new DataTablesDialect();
}

@Bean
public ContentNegotiatingViewResolver contentNegotiatingViewResolver() {
    ContentNegotiatingViewResolver viewResolver = new ContentNegotiatingViewResolver();

    List<ViewResolver> viewResolvers = new ArrayList<ViewResolver>();
    viewResolvers.add(thymeleafViewResolver());
    viewResolver.setViewResolvers(viewResolvers);

    return viewResolver;
}
```

The interesting part of my template:

```
<table id="reviewtable" >
  <tbody class="gridtable">
    <tr>
         <td >compare:</td>
        <td th:text="${row.sys1Val}">111</td>
        <td th:text="${row.sys2Val}">223</td>
    </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi! Could you please post a code snippet that shows your usage of the DatatablesDialect? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [bug](https://github.com/dandelion/issues/issues/149) which will fixed in Dandelion-Datatables 0.9.0.

Meanwhile, there are 2 solutions:

- indeed, don't use the DatatablesDialect at all :-/
- or use the DatatablesDialect in all tables displayed on the same page